# Creating a bokeh-like background effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

How to create this bokeh background effect with the help of Photoshop?

[image: multicolored]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this effect is called bokeh effect lots of website now a days  using this in lack of proper background this look good if used wisely,you can download brushes if not easy with the tutorials...

there is a list of sites how beautifully they are using this effect

- [bokeh effect in web design](http://webdesignfan.com/bokeh-effect-in-web-design/)

Tutorials :

giving tutorials  links help in time you can follow them whenever you want to and make them as bookmark to use in future i do the same and it help me whenever i need to decorate my background...

- [awesome bokeh effect from abdujedo](http://abduzeedo.com/awesome-digital-bokeh-effect-photoshop)
- [15 bokeh effect used in web](http://www.photoshopwebsite.com/photoshop-tutorials/15-bokeh-effects-photoshop-tutorials-100bokeh-brushes-for-free-download/)

Brush :

- [bokeh effect photoshop brush](http://navback.deviantart.com/art/4-Bokeh-Photoshop-Brushes-136682189)

hope this will help...:)

Comment: i recognized the image from a lifehacker post. AFAICT the op's image is a color adjusted version of the one at the abuzeedo link

Comment: yes nice catch...

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1) Create your background with either a solid color, or as in your example - a gradient. You can use the gradient tool to achieve this.

2) Create a circle using the circle shape tool and holding Shift to constrain it to a proper circle. Make the circle's fill color white, and lower the fill to around 40%.

3) Double click the layer to bring up Layer Styles dialogue, and add a white stroke to the circle of two or three pixels, and click OK.

4) Now select the circle layer from the layers palette and go to the Layer menu > Smart Objects > Convert to Smart Object.

5) Go to Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur > 3px.

6) Next go back to the Layers palette and set the blending mode of your circle to "Overlay"

7) Simply duplicate that circle smart object several times and place it in several locations around your canvas. You can resize it, and adjust the level of the Gaussian blur on the fly to achieve the effect above. You can also adjust the opacity of each layer individually to simulate distance. And you can duplicate some circles and let them just sit exactly on top of each other to increase the intensity of that particular circle.

I created this example from these same exact steps for you:

[image]

I have also made several of these background for sale at GraphicRiver.net. You can get a [whole pack for 3 bucks here](http://graphicriver.net/item/abstract-textured-blur-backgrounds/83176) if you want to save the hassle of having to make them yourself.

Comment: +1 for your answer but i suggest you to create brush and play with the same preset create flying circle brush this will save your time,you don't have to create shape every time...

Comment: @Jack well, it's up to community to decide (by voting). He did tell the whole process, so anyone could save the $3, *and* he did disclose his affiliation. If the answer was just a link or if some steps were "censored" it could be seen as a spam. I think the answer is great: it offers instructions for a crafty designer and a one-stop hassle-free ready-to-use paid option for the *real* designer. ;-)

Comment: i have no issues with him i thought might be its not genuine...it would be nice if he get 3 $  :) @jag2007 what you think about partnership :D?

Comment: hey jag can you tell me how to roll in graphicriver.net, i seen your portfolio there its awesome.

Comment: Sorry Jack, I'm not understanding your question. What do you mean by how to "roll in"?? Do you mean how to join their site as an author? And thank you for the kind words.

Comment: yep jag i want to know how to become author as your are earning awesome with your awesome creations i also want to give a try who knows what i'll get

Comment: @Jack, you can simply go to this page for instructions: http://graphicriver.net/wiki/selling/author-selling/author-program?ref=jglovier

Answer (score 0):

Create some blobs and run it through the *Lens Blur* filter.